# Prevent option popup when launching a bash application

Tags: bash

when I double click on my bash (.sh) application Ubuntu asks me if I would like to reun the application in the terminal, just run the app or display its contents. How canI prevent this popup from popping up? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See "Edit" > "Preferences" > "Tab behaviour" (or press <kbd>alt-e</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd>)

[image]